# using double and single quots in calling a system command using python

Tags: python

can some one quickly help me to run the below system command using python?

command i want to run:
(msend -v -n CELL -a CLASS -b "slot1= 'variable' " -m "my message")

all the single and double quots has to be there. and variable will contain the actuall value which needs to be submitted for every different run.

Thanks in advance,
Kaushik KM

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? Show your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.
Until you have a demonstrable problem, you do not have a Stack Overflow posting.

Comment: "the actuall value which needs to be submitted for every different run" What values? What do you actually need help with?

Comment: i am reading a file and getting the names for the servers and storing in the variable with comma sapeated values.
now i want to invoke the above command and in place of variable i want all those server names to be submitted while invoking the command

Comment: You should use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module and pass the command and its arguments as a list. Then the quotes won't be much of an issue.

Comment: `command = ["msend", "-n", "NORD02", "-a", "PATROL_EV", "-b", "mc_object=", PA_down_list , "One or more Patrol Agents are down" ]
returned_value = subprocess.call(command, shell=True)`

here i want the PA_down_list value to be submitted with in single quots

Answer (score -1):

```
import os 
os.system("msend -v -n CELL -a CLASS -b \"slot1= 'variable' \" -m \"my message\"")
```